type data for props undefined in local component vue3.js with import tag Vue3, Vue3 needed for a alone page
The use-noms-cpnt component is as follows:
<div id="app">
 <use-noms-cpnt></use-noms-cpnt>
</div>

I have an App component and an App mounted like this, I put a props on grid to retrieve my Grid data in the component and sort it, my goal is to pass a checked value to my input radios:
const useNomsCpnt = {
    data(){
        return {
            useNoms: "",
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.useNomsFct(grille);
    },
    methods: {
        useNomsFct(grille){
                if(grille.useNoms==="non"){
                    this.useNoms="non";
                    console.log(this.useNoms);
                } else {
                    this.useNoms="oui";
                    console.log(this.useNoms);
                }
                console.log(this.grille);
            return this.useNoms;
        },
    },
    props:['grille'],
    template: '<p><label for="useNoms">Oui</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="oui" v-model="useNoms"/></p><p><label for="useNoms">Non</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="non" v-model="useNoms"/></p>',
};
const app = Vue.createApp({
    components:{
        'use-noms-cpnt': useNomsCpnt,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            grille:"",
            errored: false
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchData(){
            await axios.get("API_URL")
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                this.grille = response.data;
                //this.grille = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
                this.errored = true;
                this.grille='{"error":"error API"}';
            //})
            //.finally(function () {
            // always executed
            });
            return this.grille;
        },
    },
});
app.mount('#app');

The data looks like this for the useNoms key:
    grille: {
       useNoms:"non",
       ...
    }

There is something that surprises me, how to define a data common to all components?
The console gives:
vue.global.js:1861 Uncaught ReferenceError: grille is not defined
    at Proxy.mounted line ...

For the line (this.useNomsFct(grille)) in component declaration:
mounted(){
        this.useNomsFct(grille); 
...

I've done the yoduh recommandation to create a watcher, now the code is:
const useNomsCpnt = {
    data(){
        return {
            useNoms:"",
        }
    },
    watch: {
        grille(grille){
            if(grille){
                getUseNoms();
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async getUseNoms(){
            try{
                await this.fetchData();
            } catch(error){
                this.grille="{'error':'errorAPI'}";
            }
            console.log('Grille -> ... '+this.grille);
            if(this.grille.useNoms==="non"){
            //tried grille.useNoms
                this.useNoms="non";
                console.log(this.useNoms);
            } else {
                this.useNoms="oui";
                console.log(this.useNoms);
            }
            return this.useNoms;
        }
    },
    props:['grille'],
    template: '<p><label for="useNoms">Oui</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="oui" v-model="useNoms"/></p><p><label for="useNoms">Non</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="non" v-model="useNoms"/></p>',
};
const app = Vue.createApp({
    components:{
        'use-noms-cpnt': useNomsCpnt,
    },
    data(){
        return {
            grille:"",
            errored: false
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchData(event){
            if(event){
                await axios.get("URL_API")
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    this.grille = response.data;
                    //this.grille = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                    this.errored = true;
                    this.grille='{"error":"error API"}';
                //})
                //.finally(function () {
                // always executed
                });
                return this.grille;
            }
        },
    },
});
app.mount('#app');

The block try isn't do (the console.log don't work), an idea why ?
the component is now:
<use-noms-cpnt :grille="grille"></use-noms-cpnt>


Might be prudent to review props documentation (make sure API style is set to "Options"). props and data variables are attached to the component instance and in script code must be accessed with this, e.g. this.grille.  Hence, just grille is undefined.  Also, since it's on the component instance you don't need to pass it between functions.  If you're trying to pass in a value, remember to bind it to the element... <use-noms-cpnt :grille="grille">

As a response to the additional information you posted in your "answer", console.log(this.grille) in the child component is executed before the API result in the parent has been returned.  Child component is unaware that an async operation is happening in the parent, it simply executes its mounted code as soon as it can.  The typical strategy for updating a value based on a prop value changing is to use a watcher.  Watch for the prop value to change (which will happen once the API call is complete), and update useNoms accordingly.

Thank you yoduh, I was binding the name of props to the element like this:  Now I passed this.grille to the function useNomsFct() But in the console the console.log(grille) return empty property...

yoduh, I've done what you recommend, I created a Watch to props grille in child ? Is there in Parent ? I wait for grille props and Give async useNomFct which call this.fetchData(), the console.log (this grille) don't work now... I 'll share de code which is didn't worked

I tried this to resolve the problem, now the console.log(this.useNoms) give the right value (e.g "non") but the return of the function don't update this.useNoms value (e.g "oui")...
const useNomsCpnt = {
    data(){
        return {
            useNoms:"oui",
        };
    },
    methods:{
        async getUseNoms(){
            await axios.get("API_URL")
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log('Grille -> ... ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    if(response.data.useNoms==="non"){
                        this.useNoms="non";
                        console.log(this.useNoms);
                        //give "non"
                    } else {
                        this.useNoms="oui";
                        console.log(this.useNoms);
                    }
                    console.log(this.useNoms);
                    /*give "non" but the return don't valid
                    the input radio with value="non"*/
                    return this.useNoms;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                    this.errored = true;
                    this.grille='{"error":"error API"}';
                //})
                //.finally(function () {
                // always executed
                });
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getUseNoms();
    },
    template: '<p><label for="useNoms">Oui</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="oui" v-model="useNoms"/></p><p><label for="useNoms">Non</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="useNoms" value="non" v-model="useNoms"/></p>',
};
const app = Vue.createApp({
    components:{
        'use-noms-cpnt': useNomsCpnt,
    },
});
app.mount('#app');


